# ¿Cómo instalar correctamente CUDA Tensorflow y PyTorch?, pues una vez instalados no me detecta la GPU

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, pytorch

He hecho una instalación de Tensorflow y PyTorch con un PC i7 a 3.61 GHz y 32 GB de RAM, SO:64bits y tarjeta NVIDIA GForce GTX 1650 con una memoria de GPU de 20 GB.

Mi versión de Python es 3.11 instalado en Windows 10. No quiero usar Anaconda.
La Versión de Tensorflow:

> > pip show tensorflow
> > Name: tensorflow
> > Version: 2.13.0

He instalado CUDA: 11.8 y CuDNN: 8.6
Versión de CUDA:

> > nvcc --version
> > Obtengo:
> > nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> > Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
> > Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:41:10_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
> > Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
> > Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0

He instalado la versión 2.0 de PyTorch, que necesita CUDA(11.8) y CuDNN(8.6)

---

Para Tensorflow2:
Compruebo que funciona correctamente con CPU, pues  el listado de de dispositivos fisicos 'CPU' da: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
Sin embargo el listado de dispositivos fisicos 'GPU' da: [] . Es decir no detecta ninguna GPU.

Para PyTorch2:
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
Imprime correctamente un tensor.
Pero al preguntar por el dispositivo:
torch.cuda.is_available()
False    ---> No está disponible y al preguntar si existe 'cuda:0' no esta disponible.